# PRIMEFACES: Removing hideEffect from overlayPanel does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

I use primefaces OVERLAYPanel in my project. I changed the showEvent and hideEvent as follow:

```
showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout"
```

I also override css in a way that as long as mouse is over the panel, the panel is visible.
I removed `hideEffect="fade"` so the panel does not blinking by mouserover and mouseout.
It works fine in **chrome** and **firefox** but ***not in IE***.
It seems that in IE the hideEffect is still applied to panel, although I removed it. Does anybody know how can I solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IE is not working?

Comment: Yeah. That should be the issue. Some primefaces components don't work in IE8 as expected. You should be able to figure these kind of issues by opening same functionality from `Primefaces` showcase and compare with your page.This is only the issue to figure these kind of issues. And do you see any Javascript error in console. This is cause primefaces functionalities implemented by Jquery in all the places.